# How to register local components with defineComponent in VueJS 3.0

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

VueJS 3.0 provides new syntax for defining component

(https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#arguments-3).

```
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

const HelloWorld = defineComponent(function HelloWorld() {
  const count = ref(0)
  return { count }
})
```

How to locally register components with passing function to `defineComponent`?

In old style you are to use **`components`** field in component definition object like this:

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentA
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it simply as before by adding that component to `components` option :

```
import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const count = ref(0)
        return { count }
    },

    components: {
        ComponentA 
    }
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-meadow-ois4c?file=/src/App.vue)**